# Calculating Prime Numbers PThread

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to calculate all the prime numbers from X to Y and split the calculations between different PThreads.

So, for example:

```
NUM1 = 4
NUM2 = 40
NUMOFTHREADS = 3
NUM2 - NUM1 = 36
```

36/3 = 12, so each thread would have 12 calculations. Thread 1 from 4 to 16, Thread 2 from 16 to 28, Thread 3 from 28 to 36. And then add up the results.

I've been reading a ton of examples online, however, they don't seem to help, so I implemented my own version of a prime checker for PThreads.

Expected output:

```
Thread 1 calculated: 5, 7, 11, 13
Thread 2 calculated: 17, 19, 23
Thread 3 calculated: 29, 31, 37
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM1    4
#define NUM2    80
#define NUMOFTHREADS    3

/* Prototypes */
void *printPrimeThreadCalculation(void *threadid);
void primeCheckerThread(int num1, int num2, int numOfThreads);

int main() {

    /* Thread Prime Checker */
    primeCheckerThread(NUM1, NUM2, NUMOFTHREADS);
    /* Exits the threads */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void *printPrimeThreadCalculation(void *threadid) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long) threadid;

    int number1 = NUM1;
    int number2 = NUM2;
    int isPrime, i;

    /* Calculations */
    while (number1 <= number2) {
        /* Assume isPrime is true */
        isPrime = 1;

        for (i = 2; i < number1 && isPrime; i++) {
            if (number1 % i == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == 1) {
            printf("%d ", number1);
        }
        number1++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void primeCheckerThread(int num1, int num2, int numOfThreads) {
    /* Create threads */
    pthread_t threads[numOfThreads];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for (t = 0; t < numOfThreads; t++) {
        /* Creates threads */
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, printPrimeThreadCalculation, (void *)t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue on how I could implement this to get the expected output?

Comment: You haven't shown what you get as a result instead of the desired results or explained what the problem is.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Well, I'm just sort of confused on how to multi-thread the calculations for calculating prime numbers from number 1 to number 2. I think I have it set up right, however, my conscience is telling me it's wrong.

Comment: All your threads are computing all the primes in the interval between `NUM1` and `NUM2`. If you want to restrain them to a smaller interval, you need to communicate that interval to the thread function.

Comment: @molbdnilo How could I do this? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @molbdnilo Honestly, I'm just trying to figure this out ahead of the class before the professor actually teaches it just so I understand it a little better.

Comment: @Anon You'll need to store a struct of two numbers for each thread and pass this to the thread function, or (simpler but less flexible) compute the interval from the thread id.

Comment: @molbdnilo Hm. Computing the interval from the thread id? How would I set this up though? Fairly new to this and the professor hasn't opened up the documents for multi-threading tasks yet. Online resources doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Anon You don't need to set much up, just add some arithmetic to the thread function. You've already computed the interval from the id (thread number) and posted the answer in this question. (It's slightly wrong since your intervals overlap, but that's easy to fix.)

Comment: Side note: since your output is multithreaded, you will never get the output you're expecting. For the output you want, you need to gather the results in arrays and output them after the threads have finished. Another side note: you will notice that this takes more time than doing it in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM1    4
#define NUM2    40
#define NUMOFTHREADS    3

/* Prototypes */
void *printPrimeThreadCalculation(void *threadid);
void primeCheckerThread(int num1, int num2, int numOfThreads);

int main() {

    /* Thread Prime Checker */
    primeCheckerThread(NUM1, NUM2, NUMOFTHREADS);
    /* Exits the threads */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void *printPrimeThreadCalculation(void *threadid) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long) threadid;
    static int cnt=0; //cnt=count
    int number1 = NUM1+(NUM2-NUM1)*cnt/NUMOFTHREADS;
    int number2 = NUM1+(NUM2-NUM1)*(cnt+1)/NUMOFTHREADS;
    cnt+=1;
    int isPrime, i;

    /* Calculations */
    while (number1 <= number2) {
        /* Assume isPrime is true */
        isPrime = 1;

        for (i = 2; i < number1 && isPrime; i++) {
            if (number1 % i == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == 1) {
            printf("%d ", number1);
        }
        number1++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void primeCheckerThread(int num1, int num2, int numOfThreads) {
    /* Create threads */
    pthread_t threads[numOfThreads];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for (t = 0; t < numOfThreads; t++) {
        /* Creates threads */
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, printPrimeThreadCalculation, (void *)t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }  pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);

    }

}
```

Comment: see line number 6, NUM2 should be 40. In line 25 to 28, I added counter to update the range of number and in line 60 add a pthread_join call to wait for execution of the first thread for invoking another.